# Single Sign on Keyrock-Grafana doesn't work

Tags: single-sign-on, grafana, fiware, fiware-keyrock

I'm trying to use Keyrock to offer Single Sign-on on different platforms. Specifically, I want to offer that service in Grafana. I've seen the configuration to be changed in Grafana and my docker-compose is like this:

```
version: "3.1"
    services:

      grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:5.1.0
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
        networks:
          default:
           ipv4_address: 172.18.1.4
        environment:
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=90be8de5-69dc-4b9a-9cc3-962cca534410
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=9e98964b-5043-4086-9657-51f1d8c11fe0
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_ENABLED=true
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_AUTH_URL=http://172.18.1.5:3005/oauth2/authorize
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL=http://172.18.1.5:3005/oauth2/token
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_API_URL=http://172.18.1.5:3005/v1/users
          - GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_ALLOW_SIGN_UP = true
          - GF_Server_DOMAIN=172.18.1.4
          - GF_Server_ROOT_URL=http://172.18.1.4:3000

      keyrock:
        image: fiware/idm:7.5.1
        container_name: fiware-keyrock
        hostname: keyrock
        networks:
          default:
            ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
        depends_on:
          - mysql-db
        ports:
          - "3005:3005"
          - "3443:3443"
        environment:
          - DEBUG=idm:*
          - DATABASE_HOST=mysql-db
          - IDM_DB_PASS_FILE=/run/secrets/my_secret_data
          - IDM_DB_USER=root
          - IDM_HOST=http://localhost:3005
          - IDM_PORT=3005
          - IDM_HTTPS_ENABLED=false
          - IDM_HTTPS_PORT=3443
          - IDM_ADMIN_USER=admin
          - IDM_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@test.com
          - IDM_ADMIN_PASS=test
        secrets:                
          - my_secret_data
        healthcheck:
          test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:3005/version || exit 1

      mysql-db:
        restart: always
        image: mysql:5.7
        hostname: mysql-db
        container_name: db-mysql
        expose:
          - "3306"
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        networks:
          default:
            ipv4_address: 172.18.1.6
        environment:
          - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/my_secret_data"
          - "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.18.1.5"
        volumes:
          - mysql-db-sso:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./mysql-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
        secrets:                
          - my_secret_data

    networks:
      default:
        ipam:
          config:
            - subnet: 172.18.1.0/24
    volumes:
      mysql-db-sso:

    secrets:
      my_secret_data:
        file: ./secrets.txt
```

I have the Grafana application registered in Keyrock and has as callback `http://172.18.1.4:3000/login`. When I try to Sign-in in Grafana through Oauth it redirects me to the keyrock page to Sign-in, but when entering the credentials it returns me an `invalid client_id`, but it is the same one that returns Keyrock to me when obtaining the application information.

Is it possible that I lack something to configure or should it be done in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working configuration for Keyrock 7.5.1 and Grafana 6.0.0

Grafana:

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = ${CLIENT_ID}
client_secret = ${CLIENT_SECRET}
scopes = permanent
auth_url = ${KEYROCK_URL}/oauth2/authorize
token_url = ${KEYROCK_URL}/oauth2/token
api_url =  ${KEYROCK_URL}/user
```

App in Keyrock:

```
url - ${GRAFANA_ROOT_URL}
callback_url - ${GRAFANA_ROOT_URL}/login/generic_oauth
Token types - Permanent
```

So you need to fix env variable

```
GF_AUTH_GENERIC_OAUTH_API_URL
```

to

```
http://172.18.1.5:3005/user
```

and callback url

```
http://172.18.1.4:3000/login
```

to

```
http://172.18.1.4:3000/login/generic_oauth
```

and add oauth2 scopes

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitrii. I've followed your steps, but I receive the same response (invalid_client). When you speak about oauth2 scopes, do you mean the permissions assigned to a user?

Comment: No, it means reply format from Keyrock, it can be 'jwt' or 'permanent' and must be 'permanent' (in latest Keyrocks), early this option was missing, so scopes were muted in Grafana (;scopes). Fix your variable GF_Server_ROOT_URL to GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL (variables are case sensitive), so GF_Server_DOMAIN too.

Comment: And also user, which credentials you use, should be permitted in Keyrock to use this app, and this user should not be root/admin, because this user exists already in Grafana. So create (if not created) one more user, authorize him in Keyrock to use this app, next test  that you can obtain token manually, so make request to Keyrock for token, next use this token to check /user endpoint, and if ok, try to login in Grafana, otherwise look for errors in permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much! It didn't work because of the case sensitive variables. However, now I am able to login but after 2 or 3 times trying it. At first it shows me `
login.OAuthLogin(missing saved state)
`. I searched for the error and found that one of the reasons may be that keyrock and grafana are not sharing the session at first. Should this be managed by keyrock or should I incorporate another type of solution (session files, database, ...)?

Comment: Who shows you such a message? Grafana? And what about Keyrock? I never saw such message, but I can suggest that u need to clean cache (as options), or just update Grafana (as the second option) because it can be a bug in the old version. Grafana and Keyrock don't share any variables or sessions, because they are 2 different products, they use common oauth2 protocol. U need to read how it works. 'state' is an optional parameter in Keyrock and can be anything, at least latest Grafana do not use it.